# Lamp con Ampps no reconoce GetText

Tags: php, mvc

Tengo un código en PHP con varios labels  y me muestra error , debo quitarle la función para que corra, alguien podria ayudarme donde debo modificar en el config del apache o del php en el Ampps (no uso xampp ni wampp). Gracias!

El error es este :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function _() in E:\MIS ESTUDIOS PERSONALES\PHP\Proyectos_Beto\framephp\views\usuario\index.p‌​html on line 11

La linea 11 es :
`<!--<h2>TABLA DE USUARIOS</h2> --> <h2><?php _('Tabla de usuarios') ?></h2>`

Con la linea renombrada si se corrige el error es por esa funcion de etiquetas para traducir el gettext que no se como activarlo en el Ampps, mas en otro servidor donde se avanza el codigo si funciona pero en mi casa yo lo corro con el Ampps

Comment: Podrías añadir los PHP donde te muestra el error y que error te muestra?

Comment: El error es este : Fatal error: Call to undefined function _() in E:\MIS ESTUDIOS PERSONALES\PHP\Proyectos_Beto\framephp\views\usuario\index.phtml on line 11

Comment: La linea 11 es  :      <!-- <h2>TABLA DE USUARIOS</h2>   -->
    <h2><?php _('Tabla de usuarios') ?></h2>   con la linea renombrada si se corrige el error es por esa funcion de etiquetas para traducir el gettext que no se como activarlo en el Ampps, mas en otro servidor donde se avanza el codigo si funciona pero en mi casa yo lo corro con el Ampps